# MFP CLI 7.1 war live reload possible?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

Currently i'm using eclipse with MobileFirst Studio for developing mobilefirst platform foundation projects.
I want to use the live reload (automatic war re-deploy to server when files change), but when using the mobilefirst platform CLI. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MFP CLI does not provide an auto-reload of the .war file after a change made to files that typically reside in the server/ folder of the MFPF project. A manual mfp stop/start is required.